# How do I implement accurate distance measuring to ground on a rover?

Tags: laser

I need the end effector to always be at a fixed distance from the ground, I need that the end effector is as close as possible to the ground, the closer the better.

Given this proximity I need to know if there will be obstacles (such as pebbles) at the point where the end effector will be.

I know little or nothing about sensors and therefore I don't know which one is the best to use (ultrasound, lidar or other) to be able to measure the distance from the end effector to the ground and then adjust the robotic arm.

The sensor could also be placed on the rover and not on the arm.

What solution do you recommend?

[image: Diagram of rover upon uneven ground - showing varying distance to ground]

Comment: why do you need the end effector to be close to ground at all times?

Comment: @jsotola it is a design requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider an ultrasonic solution.  They are small, lightweight, inexpensive and accurate to within a few cm at close range.  Their disadvantage is very short range, but perhaps they would work in your application.

If you need something more accurate you will probably need lidar or camera sensors, but these will tend to be much heavier and will end up requiring you to support a heavier effective payload.  That in itself may degrade the accuracy of positioning your arm so that any gain you made in resolution would be washed out in the end.